# Using CSV data as input to TensorFlow recommender

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm trying to replicate the [quick start recommender](https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders/blob/main/docs/examples/quickstart.ipynb) with some csv data, and using the pandas `read_csv` operation.

Reading the csv data works and I can inspect it, e.g.

```py
my_file_train = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv",header=0)
```

and I can view the `.head()` the data appears as expected.  The type of the `my_file_train` is

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Following the approach taken in [How do I go from Pandas DataFrame to Tensorflow BatchDataset for NLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362316/how-do-i-go-from-pandas-dataframe-to-tensorflow-batchdataset-for-nlp) I can get a DataSet from the Panda DataFrame

```py
training_dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (
            tf.cast(my_file_train['feature1'].values, tf.string),
            tf.cast(my_file_train['user_id'].values, tf.int64)
        )
    )
)
```

The type of `training_dataset`is:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset'>
```

but so then I try to build vocabularies as in the example, where we see code like this:

```py
user_ids_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
user_ids_vocabulary.adapt(ratings.map(lambda x: x["user_id"]))
```

and I had thought that I could do something similar like this:

```py
user_ids_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
user_ids_vocabulary.adapt(training_dataset.map(lambda x: x[1]))
```

since the DataSet I have is tuples rather than a dictionary, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

which probably just exposes that I'm taking completely the wrong approach somewhere, but I'd be very grateful if anyone could set me on track.

Would it be simpler to create my own tfds dataset a la https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/add_dataset rather than converting it on the fly?   or is there some thing simple that I'm missing in terms of the manipulation that I'm trying to do?

Comment: You may use ``training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: y)`` instead of ``training_dataset.map(lambda x: x[1])``.

Comment: thanks @kaveh - I tried that, i.e.

training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: y)

but it gives me this error:

 TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: I think this error is because the dataset map function passes 2 arguments to lambda, since it is a tuple of (features,labels), and it raise to say 'takes 1 but 2 were given '. So, I suggested my code in comment. However it seems it should also return two argument as it is a dataset. Does it run without error ``training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: x,y)``?

Comment: training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: x,y) leads to this error NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Comment: hi @SamJoseph  I have another question in the same scenario, what if I have more than one Text column in the dataframe, how can we tokenize and pad_sequences those columns and reassign them to the Dataframe again. Here is my question posted,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769093/after-tokenize-a-column-of-text-how-to-reassigned-that-tokenized-output-which

Comment: Did you check this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset?version=nightly

Comment: thanks - I think actually @Kaveh's original suggestion was correct and I just got the notebook messed up when trying it.  Kaveh if you want to put the answer in below I can mark you correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is because the dataset map function passes 2 arguments to lambda, since it is a tuple of ‍`(features,labels)`, and it raises to say "*your map function takes 1 argument but 2 were given*".

You may try this:

```
training_dataset.map(lambda x,y: y)
```

instead of `training_dataset.map(lambda x: x[1])`